# Editing a directed graph

Tags: gui, graphs, mind-mapping

I want a program which allows to edit a directed graph (with textual labels at each node).

A must is that the program automatically places the nodes of the graph on the screen in such a way to minimize (as much as reasonable) intersections between arrows, and to make the graph look nice.

The reason I need this is that I want to draw a graph of program modules which use submodules, subsubmodules, etc., mainly to know which modules are used (directly or indirectly) by the "main" module. There may be cycles in dependencies.

Currently I use LibreOffice Writer and to make the graph I use itemized lists (with sublists). I just omit items which were already met above in the lists. To omit some items partially solves my problem, but to have a full-blown directed graph would be better.

I am a Debian Linux user.

Comment: Do you want the "editor part" to be a GUI solution – or would you also be fine with a text-driven solution (eg. `A -> B`)? In the latter case, [Graphviz](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=graphviz+is%3Aanswer) might be worth a look (should be in the standard repo, btw).

Comment: @Izzy I want GUI only

Comment: I asked another version of this question: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/44880/3525 - now I want a digraph editor which can be used without visualizing the entire graph (because no software does it in good way)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [DOT language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)) to specify your graph and the process it with the [GraphViz](http://graphviz.org/) tool chain or some of the many alternatives.

Note that the DOT language definitions can be produced either manually, via a GUI editor, *such as [DotEdit](http://vincenthee.github.io/DotEditor/)* or by parsing the source code with tools such as [DoxyGen](http://doxygen.org/) or [Sphinx-Doc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx_(documentation_generator)).

DOT Language example - Simple Directed Graph:

```
digraph graphname {
     a -> b -> c;
     b -> d;
 }
```

[image]

Each node and line can be specified with characteristics such as label, shape, color, style, etc. and the layout is largely automatic aiming to minimise crossings, etc.

GraphViz is:

- Free, gratis & open source
- Cross Platform, Windows, OS-X & Linux
- Still being maintained after 26 years
- Also available as online variants
- Capable of generating huge diagrams, (I personally have encountered graphs with over 200 nodes and 3000 edges).

DotEdit is:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform, Windows, OS-X & Linux
- Requires GraphViz be installed.

Screenshots (from the website)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I cannot install DotEditor because https://github.com/vincenthEE/DotEditor/issues/16

Comment: `dot` (and `neato`, `circo`, etc.) produced graphs are unacceptably bad. I have no other choice as the tradeoff to use LibreOffice with bulleted lists with sublists (even though this "solution" requires to remove all cycles)