# Editing a directed graph node-by-node (perhaps a wiki)

Tags: graphs, wiki, mind-mapping

I want a program which allows to edit a directed graph (with textual labels at each node). Labels are filenames (with full path).

The reason I need this is that I want to draw a graph of program modules which use submodules, subsubmodules, etc., mainly to know which modules are used (directly or indirectly) by the "main" module. There may be cycles in dependencies.

In the [previous version of this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/44819/3525) I was recommended to use GraphViz to draw the diagram.

I tried GraphViz and the quality of the diagram was unacceptably bad.

So I see no other solution as to display the digraph one-by-one node. So I want something like a wiki where at every page I create a list of links to other pages (and nothing more, no text at the page only links).

So I can see all links from a page to another pages and (using for instance MediaWiki "backward links" feature, links to pages which links to this page).

But for my task (editing a directed graph) full-blown wiki (such as MediaWiki) is a clear overkill.

Can you suggest some more specialized software to edit a directed graph? Or maybe at least you can suggest me a wiki with good support of this?

Perhaps some "mindmap" software will suit?

I said above "no text at the page". Well, nevertheless it would be good to have short description of nodes.

I am a Debian Linux user.

Comment: GraphViz sometimes proves a bit tricky (especially for starters). You might need to play with its different processors (dot, neato, circo etc) and their parameters to see if you can produce acceptable results. In my experience, there's a limit set by the amount of nodes (too many nodes make it difficult without manually editing the definition file, which I found too much then). But yeah, it's not as easy as "click and go", and rather takes some time to achieve the results one is after.

Comment: Have a look at https://typora.io/